# parse getDataInBackground

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have a PFFile which has a url to a sound file. When I call `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` I receiving the following error. I have confirmed that my url is good (i.e. I can log it out and open it in a web-browser and play it. Why is this issue happening?

```
[audio getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {

            NSLog(@"data: %@",data);
 }];
```

Yet `NSData *myData = [audio getData]` works...

**Error**

```
[PFTaskCompletionSource encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170206d40'
```

Comment: If `NSData *myData = [audio getData]` works, but when you run it in the background it doesn't, my guess is that your problem is somewhere else.  Can you show more code for how you use `myData` and how you assign it?

Comment: @Logan thanks for that hint...I discovered that when I saved my PFObject by NSArchiving it was throwing the error.

Comment: Why don't you try to use GCD ?

Comment: @Auser if you solved the problem can you please add your fix as an answer and accept it?